# How I can draw bar chart using google chart api where minimal number is better and column need to be highter

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

I have some problen where I draw bar chart with google chart api. In my task: The column with the minimum number must be the highest and I dont know how I can do it. in this example we see how it work jsfiddle.net/h2ysjmzk/ but i need to diferent result such as screen [Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXhbq.png)

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: PredatorIWD, i make reverse X but it don`t help me becouse my chart only flip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using object notation for the row values,
you can provide the value (`v:`) to be plotted,
and the formatted value (`f:`) to be shown

```
{v: 0.1, f: '10'}
```

the tooltip will show the formatted value

using this approach, invert all the values
but allow the real values to be displayed

see following working snippet,
the data from the fiddle posted is used,
then a view is built to invert the values

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  var formatNumber = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
    pattern: '#,##0.00'
  });

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time of Day', 'Motivation Level', 'Energy Level'],
    [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, 0.25],
    [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, 0.5],
    [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
    [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
    [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
    [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
    [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
    [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
    [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
    [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10]
  ]);

  // build view
  var viewColumns = [0];
  $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1), function (index, row) {
    viewColumns.push({
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        var rowValue = dt.getValue(row, index + 1);
        var invertedValue = 0;
        if (rowValue !== 0) {
          invertedValue = 1 / rowValue;
        }
        return {
          v: invertedValue,
          f: formatNumber.formatValue(rowValue)
        };
      },
      label: data.getColumnLabel(index + 1),
      type: data.getColumnType(index + 1)
    });
  });
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns(viewColumns);

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(view, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions({
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    vAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        color: 'transparent'
      }
    }
  }));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: you could using a classic chart, the options needed [aren't supported by material charts](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)